# Fixed, 100% height div Causing Window to Grow

Tags: html, css, scroll, height, fixed

I'm trying to create a div that will sit to the left of a forum and fill 100% of the browser window's height. It will also stay in a fixed position as you scroll.

The code I have so far works just fine in Chrome and FF; however, in IE, when you continue to scroll down the page, the scrollbar expands as though the page is growing.

```
#sidebar {
   background-color: #a75143;
   width: 240px;
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   _position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   _top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop));
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

I know what causes it-- *_top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop));* --but this is also what keeps the div in a fixed position in IE.

Additionally, overflow: hidden has no effect.

If you'd like an idea of what I'm talking about, open [this page](http://timberwoodhighs.proboards.com/index.cgi) in Internet Explorer.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's with the JavaScript inline with your CSS and the CSS beginning with an underscore?

Comment: http://annevankesteren.nl/test/examples/ie/position-fixed.html

The only way I could make fixed work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fannevankesteren.nl%2Ftest%2Fexamples%2Fie%2Fposition-fixed.html&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: Yeah, don't really care if it's valid/a hack, I just want it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need that expression even for IE.

The below works fine for me...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        #sidebar {
           background-color: #a75143;
           width: 240px;
           height: 100%;
           position: fixed;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
           bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean the underscore declarations? The fixed positioning doesn't work otherwise. I'm looking for a way to stop the scrollbars.

Comment: You mean so there is no scrollbar at all?  I am just seeing a disabled scrollbar, however you cannot scroll it.

Comment: Will add I am currently testing it in IE7, as the stuff I have been working on today supports IE7 (ugh).  Just checked IE8, I did not get a scroll bar at all.

Comment: That isn't working for me. Not only is the div not fixed, but it's also not 100% of the browser window. It's live if you want to check it out.

http://timberwoodhighs.proboards.com/index.cgi

Comment: I think you have something else conflicting, your page does not work for me either.  Have you tried coping the code I pasted above into a flat html file and opening it real quick?

Comment: Yes, it works correctly in a regular html file, but not on the forum.

Comment: Okay, the height should be at 100% for all browsers, now I just need it to stay put when you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this on my forum with some conditional CSS and the non-valid declarations. However, Jeremy's solution above works best outside of ProBoards.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#sidebar {
   background-color: #a75143;
   width: 240px;
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   _position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   _top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop));
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
#sidebar-container { min-height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
</style>
<![endif]-->

<div id="sidebar-container">
   <div id="sidebar">
      some content
   </div>
</div>
```